# Send email from job queue, save status, acknowledge and log info

Tags: ruby

I'm writing code for a worker receiving message from a queue.

It should

- send an email
- save the fact that this email has been sent
- acknowledge the job
- log some info.

I wrote the following code, but I find it ugly!

Do you have some advice on how to refactor it ?

```
class MailWorker
  def initialize(logger, db, smtp)
      @logger = logger
      @db = db
      @smtp = smtp
  end

  def handle(message)
    start = Time.now.utc.to_f
    data = JSON.parse(message.body, symbolize_names: true)

    smtp_resp = send(data)
    save_as_sent(data[:id], smtp_resp['request_id'])
    message.delete

    @logger.info("Mail send #{data[:id]} start:#{start} spent:#{(Time.now.utc.to_f - start)}")

  rescue Aws::SQS::Errors::ServiceError, Smtp::Error => e
    @logger.error("Mail error for mail #{data[:id]} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}")
  end

  private

  def send(data)
    @smtp.send(data[:to], data[:subject], data[:body])
  end

  def save_as_sent(id, request_id)
    @db.prepare('UPDATE Mail set request_id = ? WHERE id = ?')
    @db.execute(request_id, id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Without seeing more of this class, it's hard to know what can be done to make it cleaner. To be honest, it doesn't look that bad as it stands.

Comment: Please show the rest of your class. You are potentially missing a `MessageHandler` object which this logic could be extracted into. It looks like the method has way too many responsibilities. But, as Greg said, it's difficult to know without seeing the rest of the class. What I do know is passing arguments into all your methods is a code-smell - `handle(message)`, `send(data)`, `save_as_sent(..etc..)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I just added the rest of my class.